# Best way to keep a copy of an object inside the same python class

Tags: python, oop

I'm facing a problem were I have a object `A` and within that object I need to keep a copy of `A` itself that I can modify without affecting the original object. For example, something like this:

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, value, copy=False, **kwargs):
        self.value = value
        if not copy:
            self.A_copy = MyClass(copy=True)
        # Do something with the other arguments

    def expensive_operation(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Do expensive operation that changes properties of the instance
        pass
```

However, I keep getting a kernel error which is probably related to this code. The reason why I need to do this is because I need to preserve an instance of `MyClass` for the end user, whilst in the background I need to do an expensive operation that changes properties of the instance. Supposing that you can't move the expensive operation outside the class, in which ways can I keep an a copy of an instance `MyClass` inside the original instance? Would creating a decorator be a better strategy?

Comment: That's not a copy, that's a new instance of the class. Try `deep_copy(self)`

Comment: I mean the class doesn't have to store initial values. When you use instances of it just have copy. `class1 = MyClass()`, `class2 = deep_copy(class1)`

Comment: the `__init__` method of the class does an expensive operation and I also need a way to connect an instance of a class to its copy so creating `class2 = deep_copy(class1)` is not a viable option.